# Execute multiple mongo scripts from the commandline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, command-line

For executing a single query script (query.js) from the command line the following code was enough.

```
    mongo db-name < query.js
```

I would like to execute (or match) multiple query files, such as query1.js, query2.js and so on. I tried the following code with no success.

```
    mongo db-name < query*
```

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongo will not allow you to do it you will get an `amibgous redirect` error. Do this

```
cat query* | mongo --nodb
```

the `|` takes the output of `cat query*` passes it as input to mongo which in turn executes any thing it gets. `cat` does not execute the queries it only outputs the content of the files and passes it to mongo.

Comment: Could you explain the `--nodb `

Comment: oh, the `--nodb` option, i don't have any mongod running , if i had not used the `--nodb` option mongo will try to connect to a port that is not open which is the default mongo port. You don't need the `--nodb` option

Comment: if this solved your problem, kindly mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Looking into it right now, shall mark it when done. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Hey @0.sh  your method works, but there is a slight thing to be noted, you can do thing using mongo alone.    `mongo db-name < query* ` works as well. I got an error previously because there was a semicolon missing in one of the query files (query1.js) and because of a formatting error, you cannot format it with Prettier or other JS extensions. Even though it is saved as a js file, it is a mongo query and hence requires to be treated as such. So **do not format as a js file** if you are trying to execute it as a mongo script. Thank you.